# How do I pass a variable to "count()" inside a function?

Tags: r

There's a block of code that I'm using over and over in a project. It works fine when I run it straight:

```
kable(
  starwars %>%
    count(gender),
    col.names = c("Response", "Count")
  ) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```

But I want to create a function that I can just call once to run it. I expected that this would work:

```
fancy_table <- function(x,y) {
  kable(
    y %>%
      count(x),
      col.names = c("Response", "Count")
    ) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
}
```

But when I try to run it with `fancy_table(gender, starwars)`, I get an error:

```
Error: Column `x` is unknown
```

How do I pass a function variable to `count()`?

Comment: It's a tidyeval issue.  Use `count({{x}})` in your function and see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for reference.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you.